# in spring boot while testing with junit4 how to check if the @Before is working

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit4

I just started to learn to test and wanted to test my method in my project. I'm not getting why the before annotation is not working

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    setData();
}
```

Comment: yes it is imported, using an ide

Comment: did everything as mentioned in spring-boot documentation.

Comment: no the logger or the Sys-out are not printing from the @Before

Comment: please provide me with some snippets or blog for refrence

Comment: Please detail your original question with more context. Put as much as possible of the relevant class if you want to have proper answers. Yet, the standard nowadays would be to use Junit 5 (Jupiter)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.